# How to have a Failover smtp provider for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I have been using a really fast and new smtp provider for my rails app SAAS but there was an outage and really do not want to move away but was wondering if there is any way to have a fail over smtp provider for action mailer.

Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT -
I saw there is a way to override the default delivery method in rails
https://medium.com/@harlow/email-failover-with-multismtp-1b642141e543

But are there any other methods or has anyone tried that method?